# Docker Container: pinging for a defined amount of time

Tags: docker, networking, ping

I am using an alpine container to ping another docker container.
I want to ping my docker container for 3 minutes and pipe the output to a ping.csv file.
I used the Dockerfile that I will post in the code section.
It is happening is that after a few seconds the container is in exited status.
Any idea on how can I solve it?
Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT timeout --preserve-status 180 ping 172.19.1.3 > ping.csv
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to update your `timeout` package:

```
apk update && apk add --no-cache coreutils
```

the problem is that `timeout` on this image does not recognize the `--preserve-status`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using:

```
ENTRYPOINT ping -w 180 172.19.1.3 > ping.csv
```

Thanks anyway for the help :)